# solr installation issue

Tags: java, solr

Hi I'm a fairly new programmer whos trying to install Solr on Mac osx 10.6.8.

I'm following this tutorial: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/tutorial.html

The only two requirements are a Solr release and Java 1.6 or better. I have installed Solr, and used `java -version` to see what my java version is, which is 1.6.0_33.

I have cd'd into the solr/solr/example folder, which works fine. Then I use `java -jar start.jar` as it says in the tutorial but get:

```
Unable to access jarfile start.jar
```

Why is this doing this? My java version is as up to date as it says it should be?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: in that dir, what does ls *.jar output?

Comment: `-bash: *.jar: command not found`

Comment: @rainkinz meant `ls *.jar`

Comment: @NishantShreshth, Oh thanks. In that case: `ls: *.jar: No such file or directory`

Comment: Which means you're in the wrong directory. You should be where the `start.jar` is before running the `java -jar` command.

Comment: If you're already in `solr-4.1.0/example` directory and you can't find any `start.jar`, there is a big chance that the solr copy on your machine is incomplete. Try to download it again.

Comment: @NishantShreshth, That worked. Could You make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Jake Sure. Added as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already in `solr-4.1.0/example` directory and you can't find any `start.jar`, there is a big chance that the solr copy on your machine is incomplete. Try to download it again and redo the steps.